# How to change just one color value for multiple objects in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

When making and experimenting with color schemes in Illustrator, I usually use a few base hue values (H) and start playing around with saturation (S) and brightness (B). Since I like similar value in my colors, I like trying identical S/B values for the different hues, but I have to change these values one object at a time.

Is there a way to select multiple objects, each with different hue value, and set saturation and / or brightness at the same level for them, while retaining the original hue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One easy method is via **Live Color** or **Recolor Artwork** in Illustrator.

If you select a range of object and then choose `Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork` you will bring up the recolor dialog box.

From the tabs on the top choose the **Edit** tab, then click the **Link Colors** chain icon in the  middle center of the dialog:

[image: btns]

Then set the sliders to **HSB**:

[image: Sliders]

You can then adjust the **Saturation** and **Brightness** sliders while leaving the **Hue** slider alone to uniformly alter all selected objects without changing their starting Hue.

When you are done, simply click OK and your objects will be recolored with the new values.

Comment: In these CC days, this dialog box is stored under Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor with Preset > anything goes