# Create the following light effect on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

[image: How can I create this light effect?]

Hello. I love this composition and would like to to do something similar (the sky over the houses that are kind of faded in, not the computer, etc).

I am unsure whether I should use different HSB values for the properties over the background layer (sky) with certain opacity for each house or if I should just use different color variations of a base color with the gradient with a certain transparency on top of everything else.

I was kind of hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What..........?

Comment: Hello Joonas,I like the houses that are like blue/light blue over the heavy sky.

What I would like to know is HOW can I do them. If I should layer them over a background gradient with a certain transparency/blending mode or if the houses should be on top of the gradient with a transparency/blending mode. It is unclear to me looking at it which one is best.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding either. The houses are just a different shade of blue, that's all.  Sounds like you may be *way* over-thinking this.  Use a darker blue for the background and a lighter blue for the houses.

Comment: @Scott The question is about color adjustment between the MONITOR and the "background" image part of which displayed on the monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking things. I don't *really* understand what you are asking.. it seems to be "how to do I color like this?" Which would appear to be a straightforward question with an equally straightforward answer - you pick the colors you want.

It's just a blue palette with three variations - shadows, mid-tones, and highlights.

[image]

There are some additional variations within that to accommodate some of the details within the image. However essentially the image is built using one palette, then areas are altered for a second palette to lighten them up, then a third palette for highlights.

You **can** use blending modes and transparency to do that if you want.

But you can just as easily use a secondary or tertiary swatch group and fill objects with standard colors - no blending or transparency. (image above is all just solid colors).

You can also use things like Illustrator's **[Recolor Artwork](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19388/how-to-change-just-one-color-value-for-multiple-objects-in-illustrator/19424#19424), [[2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19388/how-to-change-just-one-color-value-for-multiple-objects-in-illustrator/19424#19424)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/illustrator-recolor-artwork-how-to-manually-choose-the-replacement-colours-fr)**

Which method *you* choose is entirely up to you. There's nothing inherently *wrong* with any of them. There may be some considerations though.

If you are working in CMYK mode, [blending and transparency can yield undesired results](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31183/is-cmyk-mode-not-ideal-for-designs-with-blending-mode/31192#31192). So you may be better off using solid colors.

For me, I dislike using transparency and blending within Illustrator if it can be avoided. But that's merely *my* preference.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I share your sentiment as well (no blending modes) and will try with variations of a color.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving with blending mode, here's the steps...
I'm working in RGB Mode

[image]

Create a black rectangle over the Artboard
[image]

Select **Transparency**-> and change blending mode to **Saturation**
[image]

Result of blending mode, you can lower the opacity for desire blending. 
[image]

Double click the **Opacity Mask** icon to add opacity mask. This will activate Opacity Mask Editing mode.
[image]

Remove **Clip** check mark 
[image]

Now draw an area filled with black, where effect is not desired.
[image]

Click back and forth to edit Opacity Mask.
[image]

Hopefully this helps....